# Sorting arrays without changed the key

Tags: php, arrays

how do I sort the below array, so the bigger values at the top and the keys are not changed.

```
Array
(
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 1
    [12] => 1
    [16] => 1
    [17] => 1
    [18] => 1
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 2
    [23] => 1
    [24] => 2
    [25] => 2
    [27] => 1
    [50] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [14] => 1
)
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: Does [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) not work?

Comment: @nickb - needs to use `arsort` given the order he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `asort`/`arsort`.  Example usage of `arsort` from PHP.net (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php):

```
<?php
    $fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
    arsort($fruits);
    foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comes straight from [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

`This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.`

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```